# What automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ have order $3$?

Tags: group-theory

Phrased differently, what integer matrices
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b
\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$
satisfy $A^3 = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix? I have encountered this problem studying the Fermat curve $F_3$ defined in complex projective 2-space by the equation $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 = 0$. This curve has fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and is equipped with an automorphism of order $3$. I want to show that this automorphism must be the identity on the fundamental group, or something nice like that.

Comment: **Hint:** $A^3 = I$ iff the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3 - 1$

Comment: @Vik Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as [is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to answer any of the following. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added context. I am not well-versed in linear algebra, and do not know how to find matrices satisfying a minimal polynomial. Could you please expand on your comment or direct me to a reference?

Comment: $A^3=I$ if and only if either $A=I$ or ($\det A = 1$ and Trace$(A)=-1$).

Answer (score 7):

The greatest common divisor of $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must make the matrix vanish.

If the greatest common divisor is $(x-1)$ then $A=I$.

If the greatest common divisor is $(x^2+x+1)$ then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $x^2+x+1$.

We can rewrite the characteristic polynomial as $x^2-(a+d)x +ad - bc$

Hence we must have $d=-a-1$

We now get $-(a)(a+1) - cb = 1$, so $cb = -(a^2+a+1)$

Hence the solutions can be parametrized as:

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & -(a^2+a+1)/k\\
k & -(a+1)
\end{pmatrix}$

where $a$ is an integer and $k$ a divisor of $-(a^2+a+1)$, along with $I$.